# How to get the value of a checkbox of a template in the controller in ember app

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to find whether the checkbox is checked or not in a controller.

Here's my template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="firstname" placeholder="First Name"}}
  <input type="checkbox" name="remember_me"> Remember me </input>
  <button {{action save }}>Save</button>
</script>
```

Here's my controller:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    save: function(){
//need to get the value of "remember_me" here
      alert(this.get("firstname"));
    }
});
```

How can I get the value of "remember_me" (whether it's checked or not) in the controller.  Can I do valueBinding on the check box. If so , can you please give me an example syntax.

jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Rtd4d/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trigger an action on the change event with Ember.js checkbox input helper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24154974/trigger-an-action-on-the-change-event-with-ember-js-checkbox-input-helper)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should probably use the `input` helper that ember provides (see the [docs](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/input-helpers/)).

```
{{input type="checkbox" checked=remember_me}}
```

To get the model that is set on a controller, use `this.get('model')`.

So, to get the `remember_me` attribute from the model, it's simply

```
this.get('model').get('remember_me')
```

Assuming `remember_me` is a boolean attribute, this should return `true` or `false`.

See the [jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/epogoLI/3/).

---

**EDIT**

I didn't realize that by default the controller will delegate to it's model, so

```
this.get('remember_me')
```

should work.