# Trigger an action on the change event with Ember.js checkbox input helper?

Tags: ember.js

How can I fire a named action upon changing a checkbox in Ember.js?  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Here is what I have.  Checking or unchecking the checkbox has no effect.

Template:

```
{{input type="checkbox" on="change" action="applyFilter"}}
```

Controller:

```
actions: {
    applyFilter: function() {
        console.log("applyFilter");
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the value of a checkbox of a template in the controller in ember app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20668285/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-checkbox-of-a-template-in-the-controller-in-ember-app)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

using an observer seems like the easiest way to watch a checkbox changing

#### Template

```
{{input type='checkbox' checked=foo}}
```

#### Code

```
  foo:undefined,
  watchFoo: function(){
    console.log('foo changed');
  }.observes('foo')
```

#### Example

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/kiyevomo/1/edit

Or you could create your own implementation of the checkbox that sends an action

#### Custom Checkbox

```
App.CoolCheck = Ember.Checkbox.extend({
  hookup: function(){
    var action = this.get('action');
    if(action){
      this.on('change', this, this.sendHookup);
    }
  }.on('init'),
  sendHookup: function(ev){
    var action = this.get('action'),
        controller = this.get('controller');
     controller.send(action,  this.$().prop('checked'));
  },
  cleanup: function(){
    this.off('change', this, this.sendHookup);
  }.on('willDestroyElement')
});
```

#### Custom View

```
{{view App.CoolCheck action='cow' checked=foo}}
```

#### Example

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/kiyevomo/6/edit

Comment: How would I use an observer if there are multiple checkboxes?  I have a Category model and I am going to loop through each Category and create a corresponding checkbox.  These checkboxes will be used to set which categories are selected.

Comment: You would use an itemController, and attach each checkbox to a property on the itemController with the observer on the itemController. http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayController.html

Comment: fields are not resetting when back to another url , please suggest a solution.

Comment: Observers are not a good solution to this. Use actions like `on="key-up" action="doSomething"` instead. See https://youtu.be/7PUX27RKCq0 for Stefan Penner's explanation of why observers are poor performers and generally not a good idea.

Comment: This answer is over a year old, I've got 100s of answers that are likely deprecated or not recommended anymore, feel free to answer with a more appropriate answer where you see fit.

Answer (score 64):

I'd like to post an update to this. In Ember 1.13.3+, you can use the following:

```
<input type="checkbox" 
       checked={{isChecked}} 
       onclick={{action "foo" value="target.checked"}} />
```

[link to source](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/5433#issuecomment-120078991)

Comment: Given that `Ember.observers` are something of an anti-pattern in Ember 2.0+, this is a much better solution.

Comment: Great update, it's important to note using the bracket input won't bind the checked property to `isChecked` all it does is set the properties initial value.

Comment: In that case how do you get that binding?  We'd like to do a one-way bound input component but can't seem to force the checked value of the input element to its value on the component.

Comment: AdamDonahue I believe you can just use the `{{input}}` for your case. `{{input type="checkbox" checked=isChecked click=(action "foo" value="target.checked")}}`. Or if you have your heart set on using an angle bracket component you can update the value yourself in the click action. I made an example, take a look at the second checkbox option here: https://ember-twiddle.com/1d4a34f437a66f306ee5d6c5389fb4e2

Comment: I am late to the party. 'change' is about the same as 'click'.

Answer (score 12):

Post Ember version >= 1.13 see [Kori John Roys' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33630615/542251).

This is for Ember versions before 1.13

---

This is a bug in ember's `{{input type=checkbox}}` helper.

see https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/5433

I like the idea of having a stand-in. @Kingpin2k's solution works, but accessing views globally is deprecated and using observers isn't great.

In the linked github ember issue, rwjblue suggests a component version:

```
App.BetterCheckboxComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  attributeBindings: ['type', 'value', 'checked', 'disabled'],
  tagName: 'input',
  type: 'checkbox',
  checked: false,
  disabled: false,

  _updateElementValue: function() {
    this.set('checked', this.$().prop('checked'));
  }.on('didInsertElement'),

  change: function(event){
    this._updateElementValue();
    this.sendAction('action', this.get('value'), this.get('checked'));
  },
});
```

Example usage in a template ('checked' and 'disabled' are optional):

```
{{better-checkbox name=model.name checked=model.checked  value=model.value disabled=model.disabled}}
```

Comment: I just struggled with implementing this a bit and found this explanation of this exact situation helpful. http://www.thesoftwaresimpleton.com/blog/2015/02/12/emberjs-data-down/

Answer (score 8):

For those using Ember > 2.x:

```
{{input
  change=(action 'doSomething')
  type='checkbox'}}
```

and the action:

```
actions: {
  doSomething() {
    console.warn('Done it!');
  }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

In Ember v1.13 it can be done  simply by creating a component named j-check in my occasion(no layout content required):

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Checkbox.extend({
  change(){
    this._super(...arguments);
    this.get('controller').send(this.get('action'));
  }
});
```

And then you just call it from your template like this:

```
{{j-check checked=isOnline action="refreshModel" }}
```