# checkbox lost state after ember action

Tags: checkbox, ember.js, ember-cli

I have input type="checkbox"

```
<input type="checkbox"  {{action 'checkInvoice' item.number}}/>
```

after ember calls acttion , checkbox loses state. this is simple action code

```
checkInvoice:function(number){
            var invoices=this.get('invoices');
            var model=this.get('model');
            model.forEach(function(item){
                if (item.number===number) {
                    invoices.pushObject(item);
                }
            });
            return;
        }
```

How embers treats so? or may I reach the same result with ember helper (how to set parameter for action)?

```
{{input type="checkbox" action='checkInvoice' }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define an itemController for each item in the model, bind the `checked` property of the checkbox to a property in the itemController and observe the property in the itemController to handle pushing the object into another array.

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  invoices: [],
  itemController: 'indexItem'
});

App.IndexItemController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  isCheckedChanged: function(){
  if(this.get('isChecked')) {
    this.get('parentController.invoices').pushObject(this.get('content'));
  } else {
    this.get('parentController.invoices').removeObject(this.get('content'));
  }
}.observes('isChecked')
```

});

In the template:

```
{{#each item in model}}
  <li>
    {{input type="checkbox" checked=item.isChecked}}
    {{item.name}}
  </li>
{{/each}}
```

Sample working [jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wiyuf/1/edit) .

Answer (score 0):

I have done view for checkbox. use this answer [Trigger an action on the change event with Ember.js checkbox input helper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24154974/trigger-an-action-on-the-change-event-with-ember-js-checkbox-input-helper/24155149#24155149)

```
export default Ember.Checkbox.extend({
    hookup: function () {
        var action = this.get('action');
        if (action) {
            this.on('change', this, this.sendHookup);
        }
    }.on('init'),
    sendHookup: function (ev) {
        var action = this.get('action'),
            controller = this.get('controller');
        controller.send(action, this.$().prop('checked'));
    },
    cleanup: function () {
        this.off('change', this, this.sendHookup);
    }.on('willDestroyElement')
});
```

so this is my checkbox

```
 {{view "checkbox" action='testaction' checked=item.selected }}
```

and after click moved value 'selected' will changed. so I can filter model with selected property. Also can send to action with params