# Binding Action in Ember.Select

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, handlebars.js

I was wondering how to bind an action in an Ember.Select só when the user change the category i could perform other operations:

```
{{view Ember.Select class="form-control" id="PackCategory"
            content=Categories
            optionValuePath="content.categoryId"
            optionLabelPath="content.name"
            value=VendingAdminController.selectedPack.categoryId}}
```

and also how to specify the view as the target?

Thank you

Comment: You could follow the same pattern put forth in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24154974/trigger-an-action-on-the-change-event-with-ember-js-checkbox-input-helper/24155149#24155149

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like kingpin suggested,

Just create a function in your controller that observes the value property of the `{{select}}`

```
onSelectedPackChange:function(){
  //insert the code that needs to be excuted on change here
}.observes('selectedPack.categoryId')
```

The above code should be placed in your `VendingAdminController`.

Answer (score 5):

I don't have enough rep to comment on the previous answer but I think the ember syntax is observes not observe

`onSelectedPackChange:function(){
   //insert the code that needs to be excuted on change here
}.observes('selectedPack.categoryId')`