# Ember Select not firing on Change

Tags: ember.js, ember-select

I know this is a common problem, but I can't get an Ember.Select view to fire on its value changing. I'd either like to update the selectedInvitation based on the selection in the drop down, or call an action that will perform this behavior.

I've tried variations on [Binding Action in Ember.Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25490556/binding-action-in-ember-select) and haven't had any luck.

**models/uservisit.js**

```
Models.Invitation = DS.Model.extend({
  sameSeriesOpenInvitations: DS.hasMany('uservisit', {
    async: true
  })
});
```

**controllers/user/invitations_controller.coffee**

```
Visitdays.InvitationsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend
  selectedInvitationObserver: (->
    debugger
    if @get('selectedInvitation')
      @get('selectedInvitation')._data.event
  ).observes('selectedInvitation')

  actions:
    setSelectedInvitation: (invitation) ->
      debugger
      if invitation
        @set 'selectedInvitation', invitation
```

**invitations.emblem**

```
.input-group.full-width
   = view Em.Select contentBinding=selectedInvitation.sameSeriesOpenInvitations optionValuePath="content" optionLabelPath="content.event.startTimeFormatted" value="selectedInvitation" class="form-control"
```

Comment: First of all try using selected=selectedInvitation instead of value. Maybe it already solves the issue

Comment: Thanks @ahmed.hoban but this doesn't work, with or without quotes

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @ahmed.hoban who got me in the right direction. I didn't need an action or anything. Since I wanted to deal with the object and not just the id, I really only needed to change the Ember.Select view's *selection* attribute to the object I wanted to observe change:

```
.input-group.full-width
  = view Em.Select content=selectedInvitation.sameSeriesInvitations optionValuePath="content.id" optionLabelPath="content.visit.startTimeFormatted" selection=selectedInvitation class="form-control"
```

Comment: your welcome, as your upvote would be :) Ah i see now, there was a typo. Sorry.