# How to set checkbox property checked from model using Ember 2.x?

Tags: ember.js

Is there a way to bind the property of a checkbox to a property in the model, for example:

I have this simple model on a route:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
   model:function(params) {
       return { "isAdmin": true }
   } 
});
```

And on the template I want to display the checkbox checked when the isAdmin is true:

```
 <input id="adminControll" name="isAdmin" type="checkbox" onchange={{action "toggleAdmin" model.isAdmin}} />
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Ember 1.13.3 you can do the following:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked={{model.isAdmin}} 
        onchange={{action "toggleAdmin" value="target.checked"}}>
```

controller (or component):

```
actions: {
   toggleAdmin(value) {
      this.set('model.isAdmin', value);
     // Do something useful
   }
}
```

Here is [Ember Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/4ec1a6dec432c161e6efb63094531b4e?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `{{input}}` helper,

```
{{input type="checkbox" name="isEmberized" checked=isEmberized}}
```

And bind the `checked` property to `model.isAdmin`

```
{{input type="checkbox" name="isEmberized" checked=model.isAdmin}}
```

A working sample is [here](https://ember-twiddle.com/8781345c7f2c99756b370aedf03835f9?openFiles=routes.application.js%2C) (via ember-twiddle.com).

You can read more about how to use the `input` (checkbox in this case) Ember helper at link below,

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#toc_checkbox

If you need to handle actions read here,

https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/templates/input-helpers/#toc_actions

If you really do NOT want to user the `input` helper, set the `value` attribute for the `input` HTML element instead of passing it to the action.

Let me know if above info. solve your problem.

Comment: this works, but now my action does not. Is there a way to trigger the action when the checked changes?

Comment: What action you need to handle? And what does it used for?

Comment: when the checked value changes I need to  recalculate some values, if my user is an admin I query an ajax service to get the current rate of discount.

Comment: Can you just make the recalculate value to another computed property?

Comment: I don't think so, because my model is a custom model created from many data sources. Basically my model is a return Ember.$.ajax().then(function () { return Ember.$.ajax()})

Comment: I see, I am working on a minimal demo to meet your requirement

Comment: I have checked the documentation which state that the input `checkbox` does not provide an action. The solution is to create an observer function which observe the value of the checkbox and get called everytime the value changes. http://stackoverflow.com/a/24155149/2226315

Comment: Yes that works. I just have to use a self reference in order to call the actions

Comment: Good job! Glad you have figure out by yourself. Read the doc throughly if you have spared time which make you a power user for anything!